# PDF X-1a:2001 format in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I need generate a PDF file  in format X-1a:2001 using Photoshop or InDesign, and write over it using PHP (or other language).. using a specific font (inside pdf file).. and export it as X-1a:2001 also..

It's possible? I googled but found nothing about it.

Anyone already did something like that?

Thanks.

I tried open x-1a:2001 pdf in FPDF as sourcefile.. but, when i exported, it loses x-1a:2001 format

Comment: What have you already tried? Which bit of the process isn't working for you? Suggest you check out the instructions here to help improve this question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as literally as possible: yes, it's possible.

PDF/X-1a is not magic, it's just a very well defined subset of PDF. So, as long as the objects you add to the PDF/X-1a file are compliant to the specification (which, for example, says that all objects must be in a few well-defined color spaces such as CMYK, gray or spot color), you won't break compliancy.

Of course the second requirement is that your PDF engine (the library you end up using) does the right thing as well. It shouldn't throw away the PDF/X-1a identification in the file and it shouldn't add content that makes the file non-compliant.

By the way, don't rely on simply looking at the file's metadata to determine whether it is PDF/X-1a compliant. That metadata only says the file *claims* to be compliant; which has nothing to do with the file actually *being* compliant.